# I am trying to find a button in selenium webDriver. I am having issues finding an element text that includes spacesusing xpath

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML:

```
<a class="editorButton" href="javascript:validateAndSubmit(document.form,'/Dispatcher?page=ExpressReqEditor&element=Submit&sig=R2pneG9IbTVSaFh0MEo4ZWFEQkxlUWZpQkhjPTtORFpsWVRNeE56UXRaamt3TkMwMFpqaGpMV0kxWlRZdE5ESXpOREJpWVRSbU5EQmk7cGFnZTtlbGVtZW50');">  submit  </a>
```

I have tried every thing i can think of with no luck. The only way i can find it is by its xpath:

```
html/body/form/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[52]/td[2]/a[3] >
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), ' Submit ')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,' Submit ')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(normalize-space(.),' Submit ')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(normalize-space(.),'Submit')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), '&nbsp&nbspsubmit&nbsp&nbsp')]")).click(); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(), ' submit ')]")).click();
```

Any help would be great

Comment: btw the case was cut and paste issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about xpath with `class` name and partial `href`?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='editorButton' and contains(@href, 'javascript:validateAndSubmit')]")).click();
```

Also note that XPath is case sensitive, your example code snippets are mixing `Submit` and `submit`, which could be issue, you might want to double check which one you want exactly.

Comment: You are my fricking hero! I've been working on this for hours.  Thanks

Comment: sorry new to this I just did it. Thanks again